# use svg images in vue-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, vue-native

In my vue-native app, I want to display SVG images from local.

And for this I have tried react-native-svg-uri (https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri). The steps I followed to use it are:-

npm install react-native-svg-uri --save

react-native link react-native-svg

However while I try to use any of the following methods to render svg on screen, it displays nothing:-

```
<svg-uri width="200" height="200" source="{uri:'http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg'}"/>

<svg-uri width="200" height="200" :svgXmlData="testSvg"/>

<svg-uri :source="require('../../assets/images/colour.svg')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

could it be that what you're using is a react native way of doing this instead of vue native? I believe that the syntax is a bit different. However i'm quit sure it should work, perhaps you could change try and compare the vue native syntax to this one and mess around with it

Answer (score 0):

Vue Native has the feature to run React Native plugins.

Just before the **export default** inside **script tag** this needs to be added:

```
import Vue from 'vue-native-core'
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';

Vue.component('svg-uri', SvgUri)
```

And it can be used inside **template**:

```
<svg-uri :width="25" :height="25" :uri="image_url"></svg-uri>
```

---

Alternatively, component is automatically converted to `kebab case (hyphen-delimited)` with:

```
export default {
  components: { SvgUri }, // now svg-uri can be used
}
```